# Show that $S= \{C_1\setminus C_2: C_1, C_2 \text{ closed} \}$ is a semiring.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a topological space, then show that the collection $$S= \{C \cap O:C \text{ closed and }O \text{ open} \} = \{C_1\setminus C_2: C_1, C_2 \text{ closed} \}$$ is a semiring of subsets of $X$.

If $C_1$ is closed in $X$, then $C_1\setminus C_1 = \emptyset \in S$. That is, $\emptyset \in S$.

Let $A, B \in S$, then $A= C_1\setminus C_2$ and $B = C_3\setminus C_4$ where $C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$ are closed sets in $X$. Now $$A\cap B = (C_1 \setminus C_2)\cap (C_3\setminus C_4)$$

How do I show that this is in $S$?

Also, how do I show the final property: If $A,B \in S$ then there exists $C_1 C_2, \dots C_n \in S$ such that $$A\setminus B = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i,$$ with $C_i\cap C_j =\emptyset$ when $i \neq j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, note that

$$\begin{align*}
A\cap B&=(C_1\setminus C_2)\cap(C_3\setminus C_4)\\
&=C_1\cap(X\setminus C_2)\cap C_3\cap(X\setminus C_4)\\
&=C_1\cap C_3\cap X\setminus(C_2\cup C_4)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where $C_1\cap C_3$ is closed, and $X\setminus(C_2\cup C_4)$ is open.

For the second, let $A=C_1\cap U_1$ and $B=C_2\cap U_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are closed, and $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open. Verify that

$$\begin{align*}
A\setminus B&=(C_1\cap U_1)\setminus(C_2\cap U_2)\\
&=C_1\cap U_1\cap\big(X\setminus(C_2\cap U_2)\big)\\
&=C_1\cap U_1\cap\big((X\setminus C_2)\cup(X\setminus U_2)\big)\\
&=\big(C_1\cap U_1\cap(X\setminus C_2)\big)\cup\big(C_1\cap U_1\cap(X\setminus U_2)\big)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Let $V=X\setminus C_2$ and $H=X\setminus U_2$; $V$ is open, $H$ is closed. Now verify that

$$\begin{align*}
A\setminus B&=(C_1\cap U_1\cap V)\cup(C_1\cap U_1\cap H)\\
&=(C_1\cap U_1\cap V)\cup\big(C_1\cap U_1\cap(H\setminus V)\big)
\end{align*}$$

and that $C_1\cap U_1\cap V$ and $C_1\cap U_1\cap(H\setminus V)$ are disjoint members of $S$.